# Кнопка добавления/удаления клавиатуры в Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, смена-языка

Двух клавиатур иногда не хватает - например, какую статью в местный журнал написать - теперь по закону только на украинском... Для обычной жизни в 95% времени хватает двух раскладок - английской/русской. Каждый раз помнить, что надо переключаться по Alt-Shift не один раз, а два - голова болеть начинает.

Добавить и убрать клавиатуру можно через языковую панель, но, откровенно говоря, геморройно.

Поэтому вопрос: как бы настроить (или что-то написать, или что-то скачать) Windows (10) так, чтобы добавление клавиатуры выполнялось одним щелчком?

Да, знаю, что на каждый язык можно просто поставить свое сочетание клавиш, но это тоже - переучиваться и вырабатывать новые рефлексы :) Еще бы согласился на отдельное сочетание для украинского, но чтоб Alt-Shift его пропускало.

P.S. Да, после того как Windows обновилась до 2004, при переключении языка стало выпрыгивать в правой части экрана окошко с языком. Какими настройками не убирал - не хочет. Раздражает навязчивый сервис, как бы его убрать?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таки руки дошли решить...

Вот такими быстро написанными на коленке функциями решается этот, оказывается, простой :) вопрос:

```
bool hasUkraineLang()
{
    const unsigned long long ukrL = 0x0000000004220422;
    HKL langs[10];
    int Cnt = GetKeyboardLayoutList(10,langs);
    bool hasU = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < Cnt; ++i)
        if (langs[i] == HKL(ukrL)) hasU = true;
    return hasU;
}

void addUkraineLang()
{
    LoadKeyboardLayout("00000422", 0);
}

void delUkraineLang()
{
    const unsigned long long ukrL = 0x0000000004220422;
    UnloadKeyboardLayout(HKL(ukrL));
}
```